# WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: bash, python, path, eclipse, selenium

I'm trying to learn RobotFramework, and this the first code:

*** Setting ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
FirstSeleniumTest
    Open Browser    https://google.com    chrome
    Close Browser

but I received this failure error:

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

I have tried almost everything what I could find by search,
the chromedriver is in my /usr/local/bin/ and the project itself also /Users/arash/Documents/SeleniumDrivers

the echo $PATH is:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:/Users/arash/Documents/SeleniumDrivers

I have tried brew, .bash, /etc/paths adding too.

please help me to figure out what is the problem.

[Eclips screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JwPs.png)